# How can CDT project be compilable by itself, but not compilable as linked folder?

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I have C++ project which is compilable (the project is [leptonica](http://www.leptonica.com/)). It consists of `configure` script and then compiles with `make`.

If I import this project into Eclipse CDT, then it also compiles (with `autotools` toolchain).

But then, if I create empty CDT static library project, and refer project above from within it, then it becomes not compilable. It tries to compile referred project and produces some bad errors like include file not found and so on.

My question is how it can be?

**UPDATE**

Sorry, I am referring the project by linking a folder.

I.e. Project Properties -> C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols -> Source Location -> Link Folder -> Link to folder in the file system

When linking, a message

```
Location 'mylocation' may overlap another resource. This can cause unexpected side-effects.
```

appears.

**UPDATE 2**

Actual error is

```
Building file: <mypath>/leptonica-1.69/src/freetype.c
Invoking: GCC C Compiler
gcc -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"leptonica-1.69/src/freetype.d" -MT"leptonica-1.69/src/freetype.d" -o "leptonica-1.69/src/freetype.o" "<mypath>/leptonica-1.69/src/freetype.c"
In file included from <mypath>/leptonica-1.69/src/freetype.c:31:0:
/usr/include/ft2build.h:56:38: fatal error: freetype/config/ftheader.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [leptonica-1.69/src/freetype.o] Error 1
```

I.e. it can't find file which it finds successfully if compiled standalone.

Comment: So new project has dependency on leptonica, how did you specify the reference? (Project dependency, included as library etc)

Comment: @IuriCovalisin sorry see my update please